# Get attributes of all properties in a class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class `EmployeeModel` and I have below property too

```
[Column("FirstName")]
public string First { get; set; }
```

I need to get above `Column` attribute in another method by using entity.

Comment: can you elaborate the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof(EmployeeModel).GetProperty(”First”).GetCustomAttributes(...)`

Comment: +1 for being able to get this answer, out of that question. :)

Comment: sorry i got the answer.... thnx...... just tried again.... :) thnk you so much...